# Cordova Google Maps encountered 403 on www.googleapis.com

Tags: cordova, google-maps, http-status-code-403

Does anyone ever encountered error 403 when calling function getCurrentPosition() ? 
Error details : 
"Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."

and when I open www.googleapis.com, the page show "Not Found"

Comment: Use [https://maps.googleapis.com](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;signed_in=true&amp;libraries=places) instead, bro

Comment: @MrNeo but It was called from inside the Google Maps library

Comment: I also get this error since this morning, without any change while on firefox, no problem.

Comment: @jbdemonte Yeah, I got this error just today. Yesterday the apps run fine.

Comment: Pretty sure there is something wrong on their server

Comment: @jbdemonte well, but other apps on my phone that use google maps, seems to be working fine

Comment: @felangga For me, it fails on navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, in chrome, the failure is because it calls the google servers while in mobile, it is using the mobile geoloc (I guess)

Comment: @felangga To continue developing on chrome, I now use the "emulate geolocation coordinates" feature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88460/discussion-between-felangga-and-jbdemonte).